# Find the greatest distance between 5 separate points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let's say I am given 5 separate points, on the coordinate plane.

How would I find the greatest distance between one point to another?

What I mean is not the distance between 2 points, but I want to go through each point and find the greatest distance.

Is there 1 simple formula to do this?
I hope I'm clear.

Comment: This is the "traveling salseman problem."  It is an "NP hard" problem.  That is, there is no  algorithm that guarantees the shortest path.  "Brute force" is ultimately the only definitive solution.    Technically the TSP is to find the shortest path, but this is still a "hard" problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @DougM This is an open problem, less is known about maximum TSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no known efficient algorithm (see Doug M's comment), there are simpler ways to solve it than by finding the Euclidean distance.  In particular, we use the following properties of the norm:

Let $d^p_{i,j}$ be the p-norm distance between points $i$ and $j$ (if you want to be technical, it is the p-norm of the vector formed by subtracting those two points).  Since I can't prove this in general let's restrict p to be 1 or 2. Then, if, for a given $i,j$ and an arbitrary $p$, $d^p_{i,j}$ is maximum, then it is maximum for all $p$.

Practically, this means that we can compute the 1-norm, which is much simpler.  The 1-norm  would just be:

$$d^1_{i,j} = |x_i-x_j| + |y_i - y_j|$$

So computationally you need to do two subtractions and potentially a negation, and a sum, rather than (with the 2-norm), two subtractions, a squaring, a sum, and a square root.

Look for the highest 1-norm, then compute only a single 2-norm.

Comment: This is plain wrong. (1) There might be an efficient algorithm, that is yet to be determined. (2) Switching between $p$-norms does not preserve order of pairwise distances nor of path lengths.

Comment: I'll edit the post to state that there is no known algorithm. However op wasnt asking about ordering the set of points by distances. Op wants the maximum distance between two points. In that case if the 1 norm is maximal so too will be the 2 norm

Comment: It is not true that the same pair of points will maximise both $L_1$-norm and $L_2$-norm. Example: take three points $A(0, 0)$ and $B(0, 1)$ and $C(2/3, 2/3)$. According to $L_1$, $|AC| = 4/3$ is maximal. According to $L_2$, $|AB| = 1$ is maximal.

Comment: I stand corrected. I will delete

Answer (score 1):

This is currently an open problem, [Planar Euclidean Maximum TSP](http://cs.smith.edu/%7Ejorourke/TOPP/P49.html).

There exists an optimal linear time algorithm for $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the $L_1$-norm (see Theorem 3 from [1]).

Maximum TSP is known NP-hard for $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the Euclidean norm (see Theorem 4 from [1]).

[1]: The Geometric Maximum Traveling Salesman Problem ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0204024))

---

Alternatively, you could be asking for the diameter of a planar set of points.

In this case, [rotating calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers#Distances) provides an optimal $O(n \log n)$ algorithm.

To speed up individual comparisons, the squared Euclidean norm can be used.